# Number String converting to INT,adding to it, and back to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way in Python, to 
convert a number string to an integer, add to it and then put it back as a string?

This is what I am currently doing and it works, it just seems a waste to have to create this interim variable.

```
lineNumStr = '1'
lineNum = int(lineNumStr)
lineNum += 1
lineNumStr = str(lineNum)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? You can reference the variable inline when required and dont have to keep storing the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the functions in a single line as

```
lineNumStr = str(int(lineNumStr)+1)
```